# in gridview the datatable datas are not binding

Tags: mysql, angular, gridview

I have an issue in displaying the mysql data in a gridview. Am using Angular 4, to bind the data and show in a gridview.
    I can bind the grid, but data are not displaying in the grid and there is no error in the console too. Even i am getting the response in console.

this is my html code for gridview:

```
   <sa-widgets-grid>
            <!-- row -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- NEW WIDGET START -->
                <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <!-- Widget ID (each widget will need unique ID)-->
                    <sa-widget>
                        <!-- widget options:
                  usage: <sa-widget id="wid-id-0" [editbutton]="false">
                  [colorbutton]="false"
                  [editbutton]="false"
                  [togglebutton]="false"
                  [deletebutton]="false"
                  [fullscreenbutton]="false"
                  [custombutton]="false"
                  [collapsed]="true"
                  [sortable]="false"
              -->
                        <header>
                            <span class="widget-icon"></span>
                            <h2>Add Broadcaster </h2>
                            <div class="widget-toolbar">
                                <!--<button class="btn"><span class=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> </span><span>Import</span></button>-->
                                <button class="btn"><span class=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> </span><span>Add New</span></button>
                            </div>
                        </header>
                      <!-- widget div-->
                        <div>
                            <!-- widget content -->
                            <div class="widget-body">
                                <!-- this is what the user will see -->
                                <div class="widget-body no-padding">

                                     <sa-datatable [options]="{
                                data: broacasterall,
                     columns: [
                     {data:'id'},
                     {data:'broadcaster_name'},
                     {data:'broadcaster_channel_name'},
                     {data:'broadcaster_email'},
                     {data:'w_application_name'},
                     {data:'state_code'}
                     ],
                     buttons: [
                     'colvis'
                     ]
                     }" tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th data-class="expand">Id</th>
                                                <th data-class="expand">Broadcaster Name</th>
                                                <th data-class="expand">Channel Name</th> 
                                                 <th data-class="expand">Category Name</th> 
                                                 <th data-class="expand">Email</th> 
                                                 <th data-class="expand">Application Name</th> 
                                                 <th data-class="expand">State,City</th>
                                                 <th data-class="expand">Video URL</th>
                                                <!-- <th data-class="expand">YouTube Key</th>
                                                <th data-class="expand">FaceBook Key</th>
                                                <th data-class="expand">Haappyapp Key</th>  -->
                                             </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                    </sa-datatable>

                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <!-- end widget content -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- end widget div -->
                    </sa-widget>
```

this is my component.ts file:

in this code i call the broadcaster response and am getting the response in the console also .

here also there is no issues.when i debug the code am getting the data in the grid perfectly,however in localhost it's not binding.

```
   getBroadcasterAllGrid()
    {
        this.broadcasterService.getAllBroadcasters()
      .subscribe(
       broadcasterResponse=>{

            this.broacasterall=broadcasterResponse;
       }),
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error;
    };
```

Comment: mmm if you can see data when you debug .. but not when the code run normally .. i think is the time when yu bind the data ..try to move the request for data in another life cicrcle of the page .. like AfterViewInit or OnOnInit etc

Comment: i tried but the same thing happened .i tried like this                                                            ngAfterViewInit(){ this.getBroadcasterGridAll();}